# PHP Date format substracts when using minus

Tags: php, variables, date

In php when i use this function:

```
$today = date("dmY");
```

it gives me the date how i want it but without spaces or serperators like this:

```
02042013
```

When i add separators it substracts the numbers

```
$today = date("d-m-Y");
outputs: -2013 because it does day minus month minus year
```

Why? normally this works without problems..
Thanks, Laurent

NOTE: I am using apache and php installed on my localhost Mac os X 10.8

Comment: [Cannot Reproduce.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/XMJgki)

Comment: its not subtracting definitely, because the output would be then in four digits..

Comment: im sorry but it is.. i just entered a similar value. see edit

Comment: <?php
echo date("dmY")."<br>"; //  this shows 02042013
echo date("d-m-Y"); // this shows 02-04-2013

Comment: Maybe you don't use `d-m-Y` but generate it and insert into a variable? Maybe this generating is wrong?

Comment: i added a note which might explain more..

Comment: What does `date('d'). '-' .date('m'). '-' .date('Y')` return?

Comment: can it have something to do with the fact that I am running my own webserver?

Comment: What does `echo "3-1";` give? `2` or `3-1`?

Comment: echo "3-1"; returns 2

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27555/discussion-between-voitcus-and-mrmadman)

Answer (score 1):

use

```
 $today  = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")  , date("d"), date("Y"));
 echo date('d-m-Y', $today); //04-04-2013
```

Comment: I think timestamp is not what he wants.

Comment: you mean `$today = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("d"),   date("Y"),   date("m"));` will output 04-04-2013?

Comment: yes use like this and also set `date_default_timezone_set` other wise in Zend you will get error

Answer (score 0):

Might be an issue with the date function in your particular version of PHP... until it's fixed you can use this:

```
<?php

$t = date('d.m.Y');
$today = preg_replace('!\.!','-',$t);

echo $today;

?>
```

Comment: i'm sorry but not even the last one outputs anything else than -2013

Answer (score 0):

Try it as `$today = date("Y-m-d");`

For More refer http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Set date configuration in php.ini file. Refer this link

[link]http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php

Answer (score 0):

if no one gives you the right answer,try it the usual dirty way:

```
$dt = date("d")."-".date("m")."-".date("Y");
```

its not a gud way,bt does d job i think.

Comment: It does not work for him, as you can see in the comments to the question.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
$today = date("yyyy-mm-dd");
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 $today = date("dmY");   //04042013
 $today = date("d-m-Y"); //04-04-2013
```

Comment: echo date( "d-m-Y", mktime(0, 0, 0)); Try This